# Python TKinter adjust the text in a button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i try to develope a tool with gui in python. I import the data from a local database and woult like to create buttons with the text from there. It works but the problem is if the text have a different length the buttons looks very "confused".[the buttons looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Pgv.png)

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM invoices")

results = cursor.fetchall()


row = 0
for line in results:

    str = '                         '.join(line)

    row = row+25
    btn = Button(frame_5, width=120, text=f"{str}", bg="grey",fg="white", anchor="w",  justify=LEFT)
    btn.place(x=0, y=row)
```

Comment: Try looking at [tkinter.ttk.TreeView](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/31880/treeview--basic-example). It's a widget designed to handle tables.

Comment: is very good to know, thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your empty spaces, try `'\t\t'.join(line)` which implements tabs instead of spaces between your text.

Comment: Your welcome :) I would appreciate if you could mark it as a correct answer ;)